# iPhone text/iMessage history

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

Can someone give us a pointer or two on how to access text messages and iMessages on an iPhone? We are using Visual Studio 2019, C#, and any .net framework. Our Google searches are clearly not using the right nomenclature.

We have a phone. We have the access code. We want to download the messages, read them, and archive them offline for legal purposes.

It would be lovely to get to other things, but our first priority is the text messages.

We aren't trying to develop an iOS app per se, just get to the data on the phone.

Thanks!

Comment: apps are not allowed to read Message history.  That would be a huge privacy/security hole.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to access them with an app on the phone, best you can do is back them up via iTunes or iMazing and then view them from the backup.

https://imazing.com/transfer-iphone-text-messages-to-computer

Comment: We don't want to install anything on the phone, only download and analyze the phones content using our own software. We can't use someone else's.

Comment: iMazing can do that : https://imazing.com/guides/how-to-save-iphone-text-messages-sms-and-imessages-to-your-computer - the export won't be automated, but after a short manual step you can then read the csv files, etc. with your own software.

Comment: unfortunately that too is using someone else's software. We don't want someone else's, we want direct access to the phone. We don't want to develop an app to put on the phone. We want a Windows .NET piece of software that accesses the phone directly.

Comment: Sound good, best wishes on finding a good solution :)